# how to avoid repeats while using srand(time¦$$) in an iterated for loop?

Tags: perl, for-loop, srand

I am iterating a perl script in a for loop and using `srand(time¦$$)` in my script to seed random numbers.

In my output I get repeated results when I get individual results if I do them one at a time instead of using the for loop. Is this because of the `srand` line? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: `srand` should be called _once_ per program unless you're voluntarily wanting to get the same run of random numbers multiple times.

Comment: I don't want to get the same run of random numbers. I stuck all my code in a for loop, which works but I get consecutive repeats in the output

Comment: Then make sure you only call `srand` _once_ (or not at all in fact). Move that call out of the loop.

Comment: You shouldn't use `srand` at all if you want a different sequence each time. It is meant for providing random but reproducible data so that runs can be duplicated. Perl provides a very effective random seed internally as long as you don't call `srand` yourself.

Comment: @Mat, I dare say, you shouldn't call `srand` ever, but if you do, it shouldn't be more than one per *process*.

Answer (score 14):

Calls to `srand` with the same number result in the same sequence of numbers returned by the following `rand` calls. So if you do `srand(time() | $$)` in quick succession (e.g. within the very same second) then you're doing exactly that: calling `srand` with the same values resulting in the same sequences generated by `rand`.

See the perldoc page to [`srand`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/srand.html).

One thing the documentation also mentions is that if you call `rand` without calling `srand` first then Perl will actually call `srand` for you. Therefore you don't really need the call to `srand` in your script in the first place.

The documentation also strongly advises against calling `srand` more than once per process because that results in loss of entropy.

Answer (score 3):

Not an expert in Perl, but this is definitely due to one iteration of the loop being faster than 1 ms, so the srand function is called multiple times with the same seed value. You should initialize the random number generator outside of the for loop (or omit it entirely); inside the loop, just use rand.

Comment: `time` has a resolution of 1s, not 1ms, therefore it's actually much worse: calling `srand` more than once within the same second suffices.